# Power BI API UpdateDatasources for "File" data source type

Tags: powerbi, datasource, updates

Tried to call Power BI API to update "File" data source type settings by updating file1 to file2.

The following JSON string is passed over to the API:

```
{
    "updateDetails": [
        {
            "datasourceSelector": {
                "datasourceType": "File",
                "connectionDetails": {
                    "path": "c:\\data\\file1.xlsx"
                },
                "datasourceId": "1dc506f7-1599-4ca8-9a41-e06d4f94febd"
            },
            "connectionDetails": {
                "path": "C:\\data\\file2.xlsx"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But got the error below:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidRequest",
        "message": "Parameter UpdateDetails is missing or invalid"
    }
}
```

Got the same error with or without specifying `datasourceId`.

I have no problem updating "Sql" type data source. Is something missing for "File" type?

Answer (score 2):

As per the **[Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/update-datasources#limitations)**...

> Only these data sources are supported: SQL Server, Azure SQL Server, Azure Analysis Services, Azure Synapse, OData, SharePoint, Teradata, and SAP HANA. For other data sources, use the [Update Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/update-parameters) API call.
> Changing the data source type isn't supported.

So you will need to update your dataset to use a Parameter for the File path/source. Then via the "Update Paramters" API call, you can update it etc... [How to Parameterize Data Sources in Power BI](https://www.phdata.io/blog/how-to-parameterize-data-sources-power-bi/)

Comment: This is not a solution since the data source is not a parameter in the report.

Comment: It is the only solution to update via the API. If you have access to the dataset, it will take small effort to parametrize. Then once done you can update via the API whenever needed. Assuming you are using PBI Gateway - maybe an alternative is to see if you can add File2 to the gateway and then have it remapped in the Dataset Settings.